# Interaction between Azure Functions and F# Chiron not working

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions, f#-interactive

```
#r "System.Net.Http"
#r "System"
#r "System.Net.Http.Formatting"
#r "System.Web.Http"
#r "../packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/FParsecCS.dll"
#r "../packages/FParsec/lib/net40-client/FParsec.dll"
#r "../packages/Aether/lib/portable-
net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1/Aether.dll"
#r "../packages/Chiron/lib/net40/Chiron.dll"

open Chiron


open System.Linq
open System.Net
open System.Net.Http
open System
open Chiron

let Run(req: HttpRequestMessage) =
    let sampleJsonString = """{"sample" : 1}"""
    let sampleJson = Json.parse sampleJsonString
    let sampleJsonStringTwo = Json.format sampleJson

    req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hi")
```

I get the following error

> A ScriptHost error has occurred
>   Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpGET-CRUD-FSharp. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Chiron: The type initial
>   izer for '.$Chiron' threw an exception. Chiron: Could not load file or assembly 'FParsec, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
>   40ccfc0a09edbb5d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Chiron works with .fsx files but used as an azure function it does not work.  Any suggestions on how to fix this are greatly appreciated.  Thanks

**Update**

Chiron seems to work using the portal with an Http triggered function?  One major difference would be use of the package.json file where locally I am using Paket?

Comment: Have you deployed `FParsec`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I'm not sure I understand.  I just did a more testing using the portal, and this code Chiron seems to work there?